# with using enter key from the key Board instead of the mouse click using java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

i'm trying to make enter key react instead of the mouse click.

i have no idea how to do that using java.

here is the code and the output.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.awt.event.*;        
import java.awt.*;

public class PayRate extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel panel;       
    private JLabel rateLabel;
    private JLabel hoursLabel;
    private JLabel payLabel;
    private JTextField rateTextField; 
    private JTextField hoursTextField;
    private JTextField payTextField;  
    private JButton calcButton;
    private JButton clearButton;
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 350;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 160;

    public PayRate()
    {
        setTitle("PAY RATE");
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buildPanel();
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buildPanel()
    {
        rateLabel = new JLabel("RATE");
        hoursLabel = new JLabel("HOUR");
        payLabel = new JLabel("");
        rateTextField = new JTextField(8);
        hoursTextField = new JTextField(8);
        payTextField = new JTextField(27);
        calcButton = new JButton("CALCULATE PAY");
       clearButton = new JButton("   CLEAR   ");
        calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
      clearButton.addActionListener(new clearButtonListener());
      getRootPane().setDefaultButton(calcButton);    // make the enter key react instead of mouse click
      //calcButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);       // make  (ALT + E) response as an enter key

        panel = new JPanel();

        payTextField.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        rateTextField.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY); // Set the Background of rateTextField to LIGHT_GRAY
        hoursTextField.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);// Set the Background of hoursTextField to LIGHT_GRAY
        calcButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN); // Set the background of CalcButton to GREEN
       rateLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);   // set the Foreground of rate label to blue
       hoursLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE); // set the Foreground of hours label to blue
       payLabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE); // set the Foreground of pay label to blue
        panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);// Set the background of the panel to yellow
        panel.add(rateLabel);           // Add rate label to the panel
        panel.add(rateTextField);   // add rate text field to the panel
        panel.add(hoursLabel);     // add hour label to the panel
        panel.add(hoursTextField); // add hours text field to the panel
        panel.add(calcButton);      // add calculate button to the panel 
        panel.add(payLabel);      // add the pay label to the panel
        panel.add(payTextField); // add pay text field to the panel
            panel.add(clearButton);



    }
    private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         double rt ;
         String input;  
            String display ="";
            String output = "    Your total pay for this week is: ";
         double hrs;  
            double sum = 0;
            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

         input = rateTextField.getText();
            rt = Double.parseDouble(input);


         input = hoursTextField.getText();
            hrs = Double.parseDouble(input);

            sum = hrs * rt;


         display = display + output.toUpperCase() + formatter.format(sum);
            payTextField.setText(display);


      }


   }

   private class clearButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         payTextField.setText("");
         hoursTextField.setText("");
         rateTextField.setText("");

      }
   }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new PayRate();
    }
}
```

Here is the output.

[image]

I Want the the calculate pay button to react to enter key instead of clicking on it using the mouse.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1: make the JButton of interest the default button for your JFrame's JRootPane:

```
  calcButton = new JButton("CALCULATE PAY");
  calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());

  getRootPane().setDefaultButton(calcButton);  // **** add this line ****
```

---

Option 2: add the same ActionListener to your JTextFields:

```
  CalcButtonListener calcListener = new CalcButtonListener();
  calcButton.addActionListener(calcListener);
  rateTextField.addActionListener(calcListener);
  payTextField.addActionListener(calcListener);
```

---

**Edit**
You ask in comment:

> what if i want another key (such as space key) to react as the enter key? is that possible?

Answer:
A JButton is already wired to respond to space key press if the button has the focus. Otherwise, 1) set the button's mnemonic to respond to an alt-key combination, or 2) use key bindings to bind the button to any key or key combination.

An example of a mnemonic:

```
calcButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
```

If you add this to your program, you'll see that the first "C" in the button's text is underlined. Your button will also respond to `alt-c` presses.

Comment: what if i want another key (such as space key) to react as the enter key? is that possible?

Comment: @user3080461 for that,you need to register a keyBinding in the button's component inputmap

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels: i have another question. i'm trying to add a clear button to clear the form. i create a button and added to the panel, however, i don't know how to make it clear or rather reset the form from everything. is there a way to do that?

Comment: @user3080461: what specifically do you want to clear?

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels: i want to clear all the text fields that i have.

Comment: @user3080461: OK, do JTextFields have a method that your button's ActionListener can call to clear their text? ;) (or set their text to "")?

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels: can you explain more please?

Comment: @user3080461: I'm asking you to try to figure this out. What method do you use to set the text of a JTextField?

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Ok i got it. what i did was to create a new button, then add it to the panel. after that i added a new method to reset all the text fields to blank. i will update the program again for future reference. thanks again you were very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code

```
        public PayRate(){
            setTitle("PAY RATE");
            setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            buildPanel();
            add(panel);
            setVisible(true);
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(calcButton);// here it is 
        }
```